# Ошибка при десериализации в DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

В процессе десериализации ругается, что колонка должна иметь известный тип.

Методом перебора я нашел недостающую библиотеку, но можно ли из самого исключения получить информацию о недостающем типе, которая бы сузила мне поиски или вообще бы указала чего не хватает?

Comment: InnerException смотрели?

Comment: Что именно используется для (де)сериализации?